# PHP prevent die before executing full code

Tags: php, mysqli

I have code as below where I am redirecting the user at the end but sometimes it seems that the output variable is not getting set or insert query is not getting executed . So is there any way I can wait for all the operations to be completed before the die statement is executed.

Thanks

```
$diff=levenshtein(strtolower($str1),strtolower($str2));
        if($diff<=2)
            {
            $output="ok";
            }
         else
            {
            $output="Not ok";
            }

$query="INSERT INTO `table` (`sn`, `output`) VALUES (NULL,'$output')";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

header('Location: http://www.domain.com/');
die;
```

Comment: All code before `die` _is_ executed. I don't see any `echo` on `$output` though.

Comment: Please correct if I am wrong. Is your die statement getting executed? I mean you must be redirected to another page before the ´die´ statement could execute.

Comment: No error handling to check if the INSERT was executed successfully? How do you know that it isn't completing before the die executes?

Comment: @Ankit - technically not, header() simply prepares the headers to send, it doesn't actually send them

Comment: *"but sometimes it seems that the output variable is not getting set or insert query is not getting executed"* - Make sure you did get user input.

Comment: @MarkBaker does the header sends information after the entire PHP code is executed?

Comment: @MarkBaker the value of output in my db is not set correctly so I assumed issue with execution of if statement and sometimes nothing gets inserted in db so I assumed issue with insert query.

Comment: @Ankit - the headers are actually sent either on termination of the script, or immediately before the first output generated by the script, whichever comes first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be several reasons why it doesn't work.

The first one and most obvious is that is enough to have only one simple warning on your page (variable X is not set) and this will broke your header() command. It would say that headers have been already set.

The second problem is that sometimes the server is so busy answering other request and your $con variable will be a Boolean false instead of a reliable database connector, therefore your query could fail because of this too.

I encountered both situations in real life and I solved them by ensuring that every variable is set before use it and by checking if the query was executed successfully.

You can check if a variable is set by using this code:

```
if (!isset($variable)) $variable = "set me here";
```

You can check if your query was succesfully executed by adding this:

```
if (!$result) {
    //do something here in case your query failed
}
```